# I am having trouble integrating my twilio video api through react hooks, specifically for the videochat.js

Tags: react-hooks, twilio, jsx

[webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LxIP.jpg); [videochat.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zspu7.jpg); [room.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BahlV.jpg)

```js
const handleSubmit = useCallback(async event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('Work');
    const data = await fetch('./video/token', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        identity: username,
      //   room: roomName
      }),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    }).then(res => res.json());
    setToken(data.token);
  }, [username, roomName]);
```

This is the part where I am likely having an issue (lines 18-32 of videochat.js)

Comment: Hi, could you be a little more specific! We don't know if it's giving an error, or if you just don't know how to do it. Some errors might be useful. Also, your code doesn't have a closing curly bracket. You can learn more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hey, what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: Hi @philnash, I have edited the question to include the screenshots of the code that I am having a problem with. Will really appreciate the help!

Comment: @RevelCarlbergWest will appreciate your help too!

Comment: It looks like the front-end code  is unable to fetch a token from the back-end. Are you running the application with `npm run dev`?

Comment: @philnash yup i am running the application with npm run dev

Comment: The error in dev tools is a 431 request headers too large. I’ve never seen that before! Can you inspect the request your app is making to the back-end and try to see what headers you are sending?